# deleted directory in Git by mistake

Tags: git

By mistake I have deleted a directory in my git repo, and commited it.

I have done

```
git checkout LONG_SHA_ID
```

where LONG_SHA_ID is the ID of the previous commit, and I have got the directory back, but also I have got back the previous versions of some files that I have fixed in the latest commit.

How can I get back the deleted directory, with the latest version of the other files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
git checkout LONG_SHA_ID -- /path/of/directory/you/deleted
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the branch with the fixed files, and do `git reset --mixed HEAD^`. This will undo the commit so you can try again without deleting the folder.

Answer (score -1):

Just revert back the last commit by

```
git revert HEAD
```

That will back out the most recent commit. Then just push it up. You can replace `HEAD` with the revision you want out.

For more details about undo a git commit, look on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit)

Comment: Will this keep the other files intact, which were committed as supposed to?

Comment: You will be in the state just before you delete and committed in code repo!

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran this is doing exactly what you say it will do, but it's not what he needs.